# Extract EPSG code from GeoDataFrame.crs result

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

Let's say I have a `GeoDataFrame` with a `CRS` set.

```
gdf.crs
```

gives me

```
<Projected CRS: EPSG:25833>
Name: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- [east]: Easting (metre)
- [north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 33N
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: European Terrestrial Reference System 1989
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

This is of type `<class 'pyproj.crs.crs.CRS'>`.
Is there a way to extract the `EPSG Code` from this, thus `25833`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.crs` returns a pyroj.CRS object. This should get you the EPSG code from the object:

```
gdf.crs.to_epsg()
```

[pyproj docs](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs/crs.html#pyproj.crs.CRS.to_epsg)